# Run Node without access to global modules?

Tags: node.js

Is there any flag I can use to run Node in such a way that it **won't** have access to my globals, only to local `node_modules` (and standard modules like `fs`)?

This would be useful for checking my code runs OK before publishing an `npm` package, to ensure my code isn't relying on modules that I happen to have installed globally on my system.

Comment: This is one reason why it's a good idea to install modules locally, so you don't have to worry about such things.

Comment: mscdex there are plenty of good reasons why I might have certain modules installed globally.

Comment: This may not be useful, but Grunt doesn't look in parent folders for modules.

Comment: setup some circle ci or travis or whatever to build your code. It will install only the packages specified in package.json and fail if something else is required.

Comment: Thanks, I already use CI, but I want to be able to run my build tasks in near-identical conditions locally when I'm debugging CI issues.